# How do I find my missing car?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I purchased an Armored Karin Karuma yesterday, but it has still not appeared in my garage. I have tried searching my garages, as well as calling Pegasus, Mors Mutual Insurance, and the Mechanic without success.

Where should I look? How do I find my car?

Comment: Do you have room in your  garages? Did the transaction actually go through? Armored Karin Karuma gets sent to garage no need for Pegasus.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend contacting Rockstar Support, it's likely a bug